# Using ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue to update underlying xml

Tags: jquery, orbeon, xforms

I have a xforms field bound to an xml nodeset.
When I manually enter data into the field it updates the underlying xml perfectly.

But I am trying to use some jquery to populate the field.
This only half works as it does populate the field but does not change the underlying xml

This the js I am using (focus() used for testing purposes).

```
$(".myinput").focus(function() {
    var myId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert("i am trying to update " + myId);
    ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(myId, "test");
    });
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Could you show the xforms code of the input element you want to update, please?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. This is possible. Go through the below link and tweak a bit in your code. It sure works.

http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-javascript-integration

Basically using JS we will be updating the value of the control and this will trigger recalculation of the instances and thus the underlying xml changes.

Comment: that is exactly what it doesnt do :(.
The trigger can not be in the xform will not trigger an event as it does not know the control has been updated. By putting the setvalue in the external jquery on ready I have been trying to force the value to the xform control so that an xform event can be triggered but it will just not work.
My example above will add "test" to a field. But it will not trigger any event on the xform itself.

Comment: which version of Orbeon are you using?